# Raw transaction Error: mandatory-script-verify-flag-failed (Signature must be zero for failed CHECK(MULTI)SIG operation)

Tags: bitcoin

I'm trying to create and sign a raw transaction and broadcast it to the testnet.

This is input transaction:

```
{
    "error": null,
    "id": "1",
    "result": {
        "blockhash": "000000000000006ad3b6dcf2a1e1725eeb3f7c5e424feca4577d4c9e106d26e5",
        "blocktime": 1587495286,
        "confirmations": 689,
        "hash": "c6cbe3462b78a072ef0ff3f0b436372ad55d811b4ba0feb581d0adfefdd8f815",
        "hex": "02000000000101fd1819b6a5f2ca631fd7eafecdb021cb1e2ea28485cc72b8903967637d784aa40100000017160014030df68f3c20d14bd8e998588ca7e640ada02284feffffff0296361b00000000001976a914814a2c0bb0d155667341be55633e7351a7d5c57888acde1745290100000017a9149c5fefdc8021652844976aa2ba3e49f0933933c887024730440220033b4acb8120f25db5c83fb8ed4d73dc1e4d45e271c98d9f8ac46f2cc6de32e502200405228466f0b07ae8edc7d80d81c6c2983c811ee6d4588bf46ce65fdf000bc80121039657df486ea7bf33580ce678a2ac90b0dc2b82e97edc23d36daf1743d618d355ca421a00",
        "locktime": 1721034,
        "size": 249,
        "time": 1587495286,
        "txid": "ccd36c5467ad0d9d1fa4f4d081020c066f1fa7ab9b734d9b0cc90b491eeeabdc",
        "version": 2,
        "vin": [
            {
                "scriptSig": {
                    "asm": "0014030df68f3c20d14bd8e998588ca7e640ada02284",
                    "hex": "160014030df68f3c20d14bd8e998588ca7e640ada02284"
                },
                "sequence": 4294967294,
                "txid": "a44a787d63673990b872cc8584a22e1ecb21b0cdfeead71f63caf2a5b61918fd",
                "txinwitness": [
                    "30440220033b4acb8120f25db5c83fb8ed4d73dc1e4d45e271c98d9f8ac46f2cc6de32e502200405228466f0b07ae8edc7d80d81c6c2983c811ee6d4588bf46ce65fdf000bc801",
                    "039657df486ea7bf33580ce678a2ac90b0dc2b82e97edc23d36daf1743d618d355"
                ],
                "vout": 1
            }
        ],
        "vout": [
            {
                "n": 0,
                "scriptPubKey": {
                    "addresses": [
                        "msJaKN7KCGARZrKWyy169GzztFLx7aTRBf"
                    ],
                    "asm": "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 814a2c0bb0d155667341be55633e7351a7d5c578 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
                    "hex": "76a914814a2c0bb0d155667341be55633e7351a7d5c57888ac",
                    "reqSigs": 1,
                    "type": "pubkeyhash"
                },
                "value": 0.01783446
            },
            {
                "n": 1,
                "scriptPubKey": {
                    "addresses": [
                        "2N7W4L2UTnsTW4wYVLgBGLKoxHdFJ9L54WU"
                    ],
                    "asm": "OP_HASH160 9c5fefdc8021652844976aa2ba3e49f0933933c8 OP_EQUAL",
                    "hex": "a9149c5fefdc8021652844976aa2ba3e49f0933933c887",
                    "reqSigs": 1,
                    "type": "scripthash"
                },
                "value": 49.87361246
            }
        ],
        "vsize": 168,
        "weight": 669
    }
}
```

I do the following steps:

1. Create the raw transaction. This is the serialized raw transaction:

```
0100000001dcabee1e490bc90c9b4d739baba71f6f060c0281d0f4a41f9d0dad67546cd3cc0000000000ffffffff0196361b00000000001976a91459fe1a9f9f0a5af33396c59990f064be1ca5127488ac00000000
```

2. Decode the raw transaction. This is the decoded transaction:

```
{
    "error": null,
    "id": "1",
    "result": {
        "hash": "787a2c60c4bd1d92590e6dfe132f18322c27a2667f134903393de0e6f973234a",
        "locktime": 0,
        "size": 85,
        "txid": "787a2c60c4bd1d92590e6dfe132f18322c27a2667f134903393de0e6f973234a",
        "version": 1,
        "vin": [
            {
                "scriptSig": {
                    "asm": "",
                    "hex": ""
                },
                "sequence": 4294967295,
                "txid": "ccd36c5467ad0d9d1fa4f4d081020c066f1fa7ab9b734d9b0cc90b491eeeabdc",
                "vout": 0
            }
        ],
        "vout": [
            {
                "n": 0,
                "scriptPubKey": {
                    "addresses": [
                        "moinqaiuWShfsemB9nGcAGFZNMa3ZwPMq6"
                    ],
                    "asm": "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 59fe1a9f9f0a5af33396c59990f064be1ca51274 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
                    "hex": "76a91459fe1a9f9f0a5af33396c59990f064be1ca5127488ac",
                    "reqSigs": 1,
                    "type": "pubkeyhash"
                },
                "value": 0.01783446
            }
        ],
        "vsize": 85,
        "weight": 340
    }
}
```

3. Sign the raw transaction. I don't have access to the private keys, because they are stored in a HSM. To sign the transaction, I have to send the serialized transaction and the public key to the HSM endpoint. It signs the transaction with the private key, which belongs to the public key and returns the signature.

The signature looks like this:

```
3045022100f1f05b567ff95997c60c6ece7b78df1b3ed12d145551e41986a682b807f9adaf02201c914c74297b28a9564b17fd1e94710ed2ad0c32147b26e44e71fefdce51df9a
```

This is the public key:

```
3056301006072a8648ce3d020106052b8104000a034200045ca49382a5836bc13732efb3e66c5fd4ed159679517b7fdc48796e5b411af09f08d3a7b663610006f972162bd0f8f77a140782401f87b2f34f330777e59fb992
```

4. Decode the singed transaction. This is the decoded signed transaction:

```
{
    "error": null,
    "id": "1",
    "result": {
        "hash": "6d97a4e3239b375121b189ebb56af72c7f4111a03f1796e2ced241afe97d733a",
        "locktime": 0,
        "size": 224,
        "txid": "6d97a4e3239b375121b189ebb56af72c7f4111a03f1796e2ced241afe97d733a",
        "version": 1,
        "vin": [
            {
                "scriptSig": {
                    "asm": "3045022100f1f05b567ff95997c60c6ece7b78df1b3ed12d145551e41986a682b807f9adaf02201c914c74297b28a9564b17fd1e94710ed2ad0c32147b26e44e71fefdce51df9a[ALL] 045ca49382a5836bc13732efb3e66c5fd4ed159679517b7fdc48796e5b411af09f08d3a7b663610006f972162bd0f8f77a140782401f87b2f34f330777e59fb992",
                    "hex": "483045022100f1f05b567ff95997c60c6ece7b78df1b3ed12d145551e41986a682b807f9adaf02201c914c74297b28a9564b17fd1e94710ed2ad0c32147b26e44e71fefdce51df9a0141045ca49382a5836bc13732efb3e66c5fd4ed159679517b7fdc48796e5b411af09f08d3a7b663610006f972162bd0f8f77a140782401f87b2f34f330777e59fb992"
                },
                "sequence": 4294967295,
                "txid": "ccd36c5467ad0d9d1fa4f4d081020c066f1fa7ab9b734d9b0cc90b491eeeabdc",
                "vout": 0
            }
        ],
        "vout": [
            {
                "n": 0,
                "scriptPubKey": {
                    "addresses": [
                        "moinqaiuWShfsemB9nGcAGFZNMa3ZwPMq6"
                    ],
                    "asm": "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 59fe1a9f9f0a5af33396c59990f064be1ca51274 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
                    "hex": "76a91459fe1a9f9f0a5af33396c59990f064be1ca5127488ac",
                    "reqSigs": 1,
                    "type": "pubkeyhash"
                },
                "value": 0.01763446
            }
        ],
        "vsize": 224,
        "weight": 896
    }
}
```

5. Broadcast the signed transaction with RPC `sendrawtransaction`:

```
{"id":"1","jsonrpc":"1.0","method":"sendrawtransaction","params":["0100000001dcabee1e490bc90c9b4d739baba71f6f060c0281d0f4a41f9d0dad67546cd3cc000000008b483045022100f1f05b567ff95997c60c6ece7b78df1b3ed12d145551e41986a682b807f9adaf02201c914c74297b28a9564b17fd1e94710ed2ad0c32147b26e44e71fefdce51df9a0141045ca49382a5836bc13732efb3e66c5fd4ed159679517b7fdc48796e5b411af09f08d3a7b663610006f972162bd0f8f77a140782401f87b2f34f330777e59fb992ffffffff0176e81a00000000001976a91459fe1a9f9f0a5af33396c59990f064be1ca5127488ac00000000"]}
```

I always get the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": -26,
        "message": "mandatory-script-verify-flag-failed (Signature must be zero for failed CHECK(MULTI)SIG operation)"
    },
    "id": "1",
    "result": null
}
```

I also tried to broadcast it on https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/pushtx. There I get the following error:

```
Error validating transaction: Error running script for input 0 referencing ccd36c5467ad0d9d1fa4f4d081020c066f1fa7ab9b734d9b0cc90b491eeeabdc at 0: Script was NOT verified successfully..
```

What is wrong with my transaction?

Comment: Did you manged to solve your issue? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: Wish he/she replied with a solution.